# Using <slot> tag in Vue with Symfony 6

Tags: vue.js, symfony, symfony6

So I've installed symfony/ux-vue in my project according to official [docs](https://symfony.com/bundles/ux-vue/current/index.html). Also according to docs I've started using vue components in my project with vue_component twig function. Now I want to use  in my vue component but I don't know how with vue_component. There is nothing in official docs.

Here is what i tried:

```html
<div {{ vue_component('testcomponent', {'title': 'TEST'} ) }}>
    <div>
        MY CODE
    </div>
</div>
```

testcomponent:

```js
<template>
   <div class="flex min-h-full flex-col justify-center px-6 py-12 lg:px-8">
        <div class="sm:mx-auto sm:w-full sm:max-w-sm">
            <h2 class="mt-10 text-center text-2xl font-bold leading-9 tracking-tight text-gray-900">{{ title }}</h2>
        </div>

        <div class="mt-10 sm:mx-auto sm:w-full sm:max-w-sm">
            <slot></slot>
        </div>
    </div> 
</template>


<script setup>
defineProps({
    title: String
});

</script>
```